# Issue compiling with cvstd_wrapper.hpp opencv4.0.1

Tags: opencv, c++11, image-processing

I was updating earlier c code (opencv1.0) to opencv 4 . While i was changing and updating api's everything looked fine , however, at the end i got the error with the above mentioned file as follows,

```
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/cvstd_wrapper.hpp:45:40: Declaration of constexpr static data member 'check' requires an initializer

/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/cvstd_wrapper.hpp:47:31: Constexpr can only be used in variable and function declarations
```

I am using LLVM 8.1 and uses libc++(LLVM C++ standard library with c++ 11 support) as c++ standard library.

Following is the part of the code that shows error in opencv.

```
struct has_parenthesis_operator
{
private:
    template<typename T>
    CV_CONSTEXPR std::true_type check(typename std::is_same<typename
    std::decay<decltype(std::declval<T>().operator()(std::declval<Args> . 
  ()...))>::type, Ret>::type*);

template<typename> static CV_CONSTEXPR std::false_type check(...);

typedef decltype(check<C>(0)) type;

public:
static CV_CONSTEXPR bool value = type::value;
};
```

Comment: You may get more help (from folk who don't have opencv) by also putting the relevant lines from cvstd_wrapper.hpp in your question.

Comment: I think the likely answer is that you have not enabled c++11 on the compiler, or that these lines need a newer version of the standard. The usage of constexpr has been enhanced in c++14 and c++17.

Comment: Thankyou! i updated the code.